# $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ are in their lowest terms.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$$ be in their lowest
>   terms (i.e. $\gcd(a_n,b_n)=1$). Prove the following:
>
> 1. there are infinite $n$'s such that $b_{n+1}<b_n$.
> 2. there are infinite $n$'s such that $a_n$ is not a power of a prime.

I have not idea how to approach this problem. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Where does the problem come from, please. Also, some of this is answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796219/show-that-b-n-b-n-1-where-fraca-nb-n-are-the-nth-harmonic-number

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well it's not answered there because we need $b_{n+1}<b_n$ instead of $b_{n}>b_{n-1}$. And the source of the problem: I got this from my friend and he got it while participating in a class for math olympiads, so the source is unknown in some sense.

Answer (score 2):

In this problem I choose 
$$n = 2\times3^k-1,m=\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3...,n)$$
And denote $v_3(a)$ is the max exponent in prime factor of integer $a$ . We can see that 
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{m}{i}}{m}$$
And 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{m}{i}$$ 
Not divisible $3$ after irreducible fraction , we have $2 \mid b_n$ and $3^k \mid b$ so we have $n+1=2.3^k|b_n$ , but 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{a_n+\frac{b_n}{n+1}}{b_n}$$
Because LHS is a irreducible fraction so we have $b_{n+1}\mid b_n$ and $v_3(b_n) \geq k > k-1 \geq v_3(b_{n+1})$ . So we are done.

Comment: thank you , sorry for my bad English and latex because i'm a beginner

Comment: Thanks. What about the second question?

Comment: i'll post when i can complete it